# How to fix error subscribing to a SNS topic with node js and http endpoint

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to use a http endpoint to subscribe to a topic so I can display any messages on a webapp, I am trying to subscribe to a topic but get an error `InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: TopicArn` and I'm not sure why? I think my topicarn is in the correct format,

The relevant code:

```
// configure AWS
AWS.config.update({
    'region': 'eu-west-2',    // is this the region of my topic ?
    'accessKeyId': 'keyid',
    'secretAccessKey': 'secretkey'
});

const sns = new AWS.SNS();
sns.subscribe({
    'TopicArn': 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-x:xxxxxxx:my_topic',
    'Protocol': 'http',
    'Endpoint': 'http://localhost/:3000'
}, function (err, result) {

    if (err !== null) {
        console.log(util.inspect(err));
        return;
    }
    console.log(util.inspect(result));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/sinergise/Sentinel2ProductIngestor/issues/2) and [this issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1763) in github it looks like it's due to the region of AWS instance mismatching the region of the topic.

If you use the AWS instance in other areas and wish to keep the global region as is, you could do this to make the sns instance in the correct region:

> const sns = new AWS.SNS({ region: 'eu-west-x' });